# SQL - Dynamically add columns to temp table based on value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, temp-tables

I need to perform some dynamic operation temp table based on some condition.
(add columns based of number and update only those columns)

I have one one master table which contains unit information - 
E.G.

```
ID   UNIT
1     kg
2     cm
3     mm
```

Here, number of rows can vary. It can contain 3 rows or 4 rows or 2 rows.

Now i want create some columns in my temp table based on this.

E.G.

if master table has 2 values then #temp should contain 2 columns as unit1 and unit2. 
if 3 values then unit1, unit2 and unit3.

Is it possible? Or do i need to create max number of columns directly in temp table?

Thanks

Comment: You have to use `Dynamic PIVOT`, there are many similar questions, just try to search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `Dynamic PIVOT` and `GLOBAL TEMP TABLE` in following:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #t
GO

CREATE  table #t 
(id varchar(max),unit varchar(max))
insert into #t (id,unit)values 
(1,'kg'),
(2,'cm'),
(3,'mm'),
(4,'m')

DECLARE @statement NVARCHAR(max)
       ,@columns NVARCHAR(max)

SELECT @columns = ISNULL(@columns + ',', '') + N'[' + cast(tbl.id as varchar(max)) + ']'
FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT id
   FROM #t
   ) AS tbl

SELECT @statement =  'select * 
                      INTO ##temp 
                      from (
                        SELECT id,[unit]
                        FROM #t
                        ) as s 
PIVOT
(max(unit) FOR id in(' + @columns + ')) as pvt
'


EXEC sp_executesql @statement = @statement

SELECT * FROM ##temp

DROP TABLE ##temp
```

Comment: the dynamic table ##temp would NOT exist after you execute the sql statement.

Answer (score 0):

What i have done in this situation is use dynamic sql to append the new column to an existing temp table.
It would have been nice to create the temp table with dynamic sql, but if you do that it doesn't exist outside the execute statement. @col is a variable varchar(100) and the table #cols contains a list of column names. This was to build a crosstab/pivot result that required a median calculation (So I couldn't use the PIVOT statement) to populate the result. None of the rows or columns were known ahead of time so dynamic sql was required. (the data could have come from any combination of about 40 different datasources)
e.g.

```
    WHILE @col IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SELECT @col = MIN(value)
        FROM #cols
        WHERE value > @col
        IF @col IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            SET @Dsql = 'alter table #xtab add [' + @col + '] decimal(7,2)'
            EXEC (@Dsql)
        END
    END
    SET @col = ''
```

the table #tab started with one column that was for the row titles.
e.g

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #xtab
CREATE TABLE #xtab (
      rowcol VARCHAR(1000)
)
```

the final table could have up to 1024 columns in it.